# regex string doesn't seem to work in ELK stack

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, docker, elastic-stack

I'm new to the ELK stack and am having issues doing some things that I think should be pretty simple. I have log data that looks like the following (as retrieved from the elasticsearch api):

```
{
  "_index": "filebeat-2017.06.02",
  "_type": "log",
  "_id": "AVxqBHFg2ZHUP62Y4ofK",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "_source": { SNIPPING stuff I don't think is important here },
  "host": "LYNCHC",
  "source": "C:\\PathToTheFile.log",
  "message": "\"INFO\",\"mc-1\",\"04\/26\/2017\",\"02:26:55\",\"\",\";Error invoking external process **SNIPPING for brevity**",
  "type": "log",
  "tags": [ "beats_input_codec_plain_applied" ]
  }
}
```

and other logs that looks like this:

```
{
  "_index": "filebeat-2017.06.02",
  "_type": "log",
  "_id": "AVxqBHhd2ZHUP62Y4ofR",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "_source": { SNIPPING stuff I don't think is important here },
  "host": "LYNCHC",
  "source": "C:\\PathToTheFile.log",
  "message": "\"ERROR\",\"mc-25\",\"03\/15\/2017\",\"19:27:09\",\"\",\"exception thrown trying to stop apache**SNIPPING for brevity**",
  "type": "log",
  "tags": [ "beats_input_codec_plain_applied" ]
  }
}
```

and I would like to construct a query (an elasticsearch query passed through kibana) that will find the first logs while filtering the second ones out (notice that I can't just query on the word "error" because error is contained in the second type of log).

I am trying to do this with a regular expression query, and it feels like this should work, though it doesn't (it returns zero results):

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "message": "\"ERROR\".*"
    }
  }
}
```

The following query does return results, though it returns both types of logs:

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "message": "error"
    }
  }
}
```

Might be worth noting that case sensitivity does seem to matter (searching for "ERROR" also returns zero results). I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, and feel like I'm following the documentation. Am I missing something?

Comment: How an indexed document looks like? Can you please post one?

Comment: It looks like the regex is not handled with the ElasticSearch Lucene regex engine, since it anchors the pattern. It also does not seem to "see" the quotes. Try something like `"\\bERROR\\b"` or `"^ERROR"` or `"^.?ERROR"`

Comment: @Robert, I've updated the post to include what the indexed document looks like, with a few sections removed because they were long and I didn't think they were necessary (I removed two stacktraces, for example).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I tried all of your suggestions and each of them returned zero results. It feels like there might be something really fundamental that I'm missing in my inexperience with the elk stack? I'm just not sure what it would be

Comment: Just a guess here, can you try `"\\\\"ERROR\\\\".*"` I think that the problem 
 is something with the escaping

Comment: @JorgeCampos I'm unable to submit that query in kibana - I get a "Could not parse JSON input" error. I tried fixing it by using `\\\"ERROR\\\".*` but that also returned zero results.

Comment: Hmmm, what about `".+{2}ERROR.+{2}.*"`?

Comment: That one is submittable but still returns zero results

Comment: Ok, last attempt here... promise...  `".+{1}ERROR.+{1}.*"`

Comment: Dang, still zero results :( Good idea though!

Comment: I was looking through [elasticsearch regex patterns](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) but there are nothing that helped here :( , I was specific looking for something that indicates or  force the case sensitive since you said that "error" brings both results...

Comment: Yeah that's the documentation page I've been looking at too... from that page, it really seems like my query should be working, it's really weird to me that it wouldn't be.